# Как перенастроить локальный репозиторий на новый аккаунт github

Tags: git

Я создал новый аккаунт на github. Попытался добавить туда файлы, но получилась ошибка:

```
git config --global user.name "Моё имя"
git config --global user.email "Мой новый адрес электронной почты"
C:\Users\имя пользователя*\Desktop\web\13th> git push -f origin master
remote: Permission to "путь/React-Page.git" denied to
"Мой старый аккаунт". fatal: unable to access
'github.com/путь': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Как убрать старый аккаунт, чтобы он не мешал?

Comment: Необходимо через панель управления удалить аккаунт GitHub'а. Тогда сможешь ввести новые данные.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по набираемым вами командам и результатам из выполнения, вам нужно в локальном репозитории удалить или отредактировать ссылку на удаленный репозиторий.

### Удалить:

```
git remote remove origin
```

#### Отредактировать:

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

Ссылка на такой же вопрос с ответами на англоязычном [stackoverfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330404/how-to-remove-remote-origin-from-a-git-repository)